# Multiple data sources for multiple ng-grid in a single view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

If I have multiple data sources for multiple ng-grid (not ui-grid), how would I assign them to each ng-grid configs?

ex:

```
$scope.myData['set1'] = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
$scope.myData['set2'] = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50}];
```

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
var gridOptions1 = {
    data: ('myData[' + 'set1' + ']'),
    columnDefs: [
        { field:"name", displayName: "NAME"},
        { field:"age", displayName: "AGE"}],
    multiSelect: true,
    selectedItems: $scope.selected
};

var gridOptions2 = {
    data: ('myData[' + 'set2' + ']'),
    columnDefs: [
        { field:"name", displayName: "Name"},
        { field:"age", displayName: "Age"}],
    multiSelect: false,
    selectedItems: $scope.selected
};
```

The reason I want to do this is because I have a dynamic form which may have a variable amount of ng-grids (based on useer input), so I need to make sure each grid has to correct data within it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out my error. set1 and set2 are supposed to be surrounded by double quotes within the single quotes.